# css sprite for text links

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use an image with a bunch of icons for some text links I have in an unordered list, but failing to only show 1 icon with space on the side of it for the text. Here is what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/XyVtq/2/

my css:

```
#head_about {    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/IOA8l.png) no-repeat -2px -2px;    width: 9px;    height: 18px; display:block; margin-left:20px;  }​
```

my html:

```
<ul>
        <li><a id="head_about" href="test.html" >About Us</a></li>
 </ul>​
```

if I add left padding it reveals more icons in the total image. Is there a way to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I separate the sprite from the content, I usually add an icon tag in the html that is dedicated to the sprite and then style the link separately.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/XyVtq/1/

```
<ul id="header_pages">
  <li>
    <i id="icon"></i> <a id="head_about" href="<?php echo tep_href_link(FILENAME_ABOUT_US); ?>" >About Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>​

#icon {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/IOA8l.png) no-repeat -2px -2px;    
  width: 9px;    
  height: 18px; 
  display:inline-block
} 

li a {
   margin-left:18px;   
}
```

Comment: Yea this would work. Any reason you used the i tag instead of say just <span id="icon"></span> ?

Comment: hmm if I do this the icon won't be linked though. I think that is a bit of a usability issue no?

Comment: move the icon or span inside the tag <a href=""><i id="icon"></i> Hi, Click Me!</a>